# how to re-save image after cropping with php and zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-processing, crop

i have a function that saves my picture to disk:

```
public function uploadToDiskMulty($folderPath, $filename)
{
    // create the transfer adapter
    // note that setDestiation is deprecated, instead use the Rename filter
    $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $adapter->addFilter('Rename', array(
            'target'    => $filename,
            'overwrite' => true
    ));

    // try to receive one file
    if ($adapter->receive($folderPath)) {
        $message = "success";
    } else {
        $message = "fail";
    }

    return $message;
 }
```

then i have a function that crops a image

```
public function uploadCroppedImage($image, $x, $y, $w, $h)
{
    $targ_w = 200;
    $targ_h = 300;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;


    $img_r = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $x, $y, $targ_w, $targ_h, $w, $h);
}
```

the `$image = http://test.com/test_folder/example.jpg`

the `$folderPath = /var/www/media/test_folder/`

and the `$filename = example.jpg`

my issue is that i need the cropped image path so i can run it through the `uploadToDiskMulty` function.

`imagecopyresampled` returns true or false.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output it with [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), or equivalent for the type you need.

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'somepath/someimg.jpg');
```

Comment: does it saves it? what if i pass my server path `/var/www/media/...`

Comment: You can use any path you want.

Comment: hmmm, i have this `imagejpeg($dst_r, $image, 90);` but it doesn't seem to overwrite the original file